# Reformatting a text file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm new to when it comes to create scripts with Powershell. I'm looking how to read a text file and reformat the content in a single json style line. The file I'm reading contains multiple information blocks as the one as below:

```
Authorization        : 
                       Scope     : /subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                       Action    : Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/listClusterAdminCredential/action
Claims               : 
                       aud            : https://management.core.windows.net/
                       iss            : https://sts.windows.net/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/
                       aio            : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                       appidacr       : 2
                       http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider: https://sts.windows.net/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/
                       xms_tcdt       : XXXXXXXXXX
HttpRequest          : 
                       ClientId        : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                       Method          : POST
                       Url             : https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/
                       ClientIpAddress : XX.XX.XX.XX
Properties           : 
                       statusCode     : OK
                       serviceRequestId: 
                       eventCategory  : Administrative
                       entity         : /subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/providers/
Level                : Informational
EventTimestamp       : 8/22/2023 5:59:49 PM
SubStatus            : OK (HTTP Status Code: 200)
Caller               : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Id                   : /subscriptions/XXXXXX/resourceGroups/XXXXX/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/XXXXX/events/XXXXX
```

I'm trying to format the text as below and send it to a new file, which will get more data like this every hour.

```
"Authorization":{"scope":"/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","action":"Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/listClusterAdminCredential/action"},"Claims":{"aud":"https://management.core.windows.net/","iss":"https://management.core.windows.net/" ..............},"HttpRequest":{.............}
```

I have starting drafting something with get-content and removing the empty lines with the where-object but I'm not sure where to go from there.

```
Write-Host " ..... " -ForegroundColor Yellow
$customlogfile = 'C:\azlogs\customlog.txt'

Write-Host "Reading the Activity Log file ..... " -ForegroundColor Yellow
$originfile = 'C:\azlogs\activitylogs.txt'
$originfilecontent = Get-Content -Path $originfile | Where-Object { $_ -ne '' }

Write-Host "Reformatting content of the Activity Log file ..... " -ForegroundColor Yellow
$originfilecontent | Select-String -Pattern 'Authorization' -CaseSensitive -SimpleMatch -Context 1 | Add-Content -Path $customlogfile | ConvertTo-Json
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
> Authorization        : 
                         Scope     : /subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/XXXXXXXXX/
TenantId             : 
> Authorization        : 
                         Scope     : /subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/XXXXXXXXX/
```

Comment: Add the code you've drafted already to your question

Comment: @mjsqu I have updated the entry with my current code.

Answer (score 0):

Your input text looks like it was created for *display* purposes, which makes parsing it into a structured text format such as JSON challenging.

If you cannot change the input format, use the following approach, which uses a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement in combination with [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) parsing:

```bash
# Initialize an ordered hashtable that will store the 
# (partially nested) name-value pairs.
$oht = [ordered] @{}

# Parse the input file and fill the ordered hashtable.
switch -Regex -File $customlogfile {
  '^(\s*)(\w+)\s*: (.*)' {
    $isNested = [bool] $Matches.1
    $name = $Matches.2
    $value = $Matches.3
    if ($isNested) {
      $nested.$name = $value
    }
    elseif ($value) {
      $oht.$name = $value
    }
    else {
      $nested = $oht.$name = [ordered] @{}
    }
  }
}

# Convert the ordered hashtable to a JSON one-liner.
$oht | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
```

Note:

- The above assumes at most two levels of nesting.
- Property values are all stored as *strings*.

  - Using other data types such as `[int]` for property value `2` would require additional work and would invariably involve making *assumptions*.